# Sagemaker Pipelines | Pass list of strings as parameter

Tags: pipeline, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

The Sagemaker Pipeline only has Parameter classes for single values (a string, a float, etc), but how can I deal with a parameter that is best represented by a list (e.g. the list of features to select for training from a file with many features)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**: Following best practices, in general, of using feature names (e.g., column names of a dataframe pandas), these should be without spaces between them.

## Base case

To **bypass your problem**, you can use a string as a parameter where each element is a single feature.

```py
features = "feature_0 feature_1 feature_2"
```

and then, use it normally with [ParameterString](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#sagemaker.workflow.parameters.ParameterString).

*If it cannot be that way, I recommend inserting a specific separation pattern between names instead of space and splitting the whole string into features list later.*

At this point, in the training script you pass the parameter to the ArgumentParser which you can configure to have the space-separated word string reprocessed into a list of individual words.

```py
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        "--features",
        nargs="*",
        type=str,
        default=[]
    )

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
```

### Extra case

Should the string mistakenly be interpreted as a list directly when passing the argument to a pipeline component (e.g., to a preprocessor), the latter can be reworked with an input reinterpretation function.

```py
import itertools

def decode_list_of_strings_input(str_input: str) -> []:
    str_input = [s.split() for s in str_input]
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(str_input))
```

Here is an example of the use of this code:

```py
features = ['a b c']
features = decode_list_of_strings_input(features)

print(features)
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```